# Surface integrals in ECEF coordinates?

Tags: coordinate-systems, surface-integrals, geodesy

I was doing some general thinking about mathematics and calculus, and I was wondering if it is possible to find the surface area of any place on Earth using integration in the Earth-Centered, Earth-Fixed (ECEF) Coordinate System.

I was thinking along the lines of doing so in spherical and cylindrical coordinate systems, but I am confused because of the elliptical shape of the Earth.  Thank you for any help you can provide!

Comment: In theory, probably yes (I only say probably because I've never heard of this coordinate system before). But we can step back for a moment and think about what a coordinate system is. A coordinate system is what unites geometry and algebra. Assume that space exists. You can draw points and lines in this space. You can draw shapes and curves. A point is a point. It's only when you lay down a coordinate system that a geometrical point becomes (or becomes labeled with) a number. The only purpose of a coordinate system is to fill space with intersecting grid lines. It's a labeling system

Comment: And labeling systems are completely arbitrary. Cartesian coordinates fill space with perpendicular grid lines. 2D polar coordinates fill space with circular and ray-like grid lines. You can fill space with curvy grid lines. You just need to fill space with grid lines so you set up a labeling system. But the labeling system you choose can be anything. It doesn't affect anything. $$\int\int_S dS$$, as I've written it, is independent of coordinate system. Once you choose a coordinate system, $dS$ will have an appearance for that specific system. In cartesian, $dS = dxdy$

Comment: @DWade64 So then, going off of [this link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ECEF#/media/File:ECEF.svg) it would look like the latitude-longitude-elevation system is analogous to spherical coordinates and ECEF is the non-inertial analogue of Cartesian coordinates (inertial being ECI)?

Comment: ECI looks like a non-spinning frame as you say. ECEF is a spinning cartesian coordinate system. You are just filling space with perpendicular grid lines and those grid lines are rigid and everything is spinning with the earth. And LLE is spherical (though you have to be careful with the definitions of each L,L, and E. In spherical, "elevation" is radial distance from origin as you know. Whereas in LLE, elevation is probably from the surface of the earth). What matters most is what the equation of the surface is. For instance, a sphere expressed in cartesian is $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = R^2$.

Comment: In spherical, a sphere would be expressed as $r = R$. How the equation is expressed will probably determine which coordinate system you will use in the surface integral. By the way, ECEF would probably be the way to go. In ECI, things would be time-dependent as the area of interest will be sliding over the coordinates. Therefore stuff in the integral will be time-dependent - probably